# An irreducible $a \in A \subset B$ such that $B$ is f.g. free $A$-module remains irreducible in $B$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian, free-modules

Let $A \subset B$ be Noetherian integral domains (not necessarily UFD's), and let $a \in A$ be irreducible (in $A$).
Assume that $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-module and a free $A$-module.

> Is it true that $a$ must be irreducible in $B$?

I do not mind to further assume that $A$ and $B$ are $\mathbb{C}$-algebras, if this helps.

**My motivation:** $A=k[x^2]$, $B=k[x^2][x^3]$, $a=x^2$; $a$ remains irreducible in $B$.

> If there exists a counterexample, is there an additional mild assumption that will guarantee that $a$ remains irreducible?

---

> **Edit:** What if we require, in addition, that $A,B$ are UFD's, and $A \subseteq B$ is a separable ring extension?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Take $A=\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $B=\mathbb{C}[x]$. Then $A \subseteq B$ and $x^2+1 \in A$ is irreducible. However, $x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i) \in B$.

Comment: Thanks. But what if both $A$ and $B$ are $\mathbb{C}$-algebras?

Comment: I don't think this is true even when $A$ and $B$ are finitely generated UFD's over the same field, though I don't have an example in mind. If you're familiar with algebraic geometry, note that an injective map $A \to B$ will always give a dominant map $Spec(B) \to Spec(A)$, but it's not often that this will be surjective.

Comment: @user237522 Okay here we go: Consider $A=\mathbb{C}[x] \to B=\mathbb{C}[x, \frac{1}{x}]$, where $x \mapsto x$. Then $(x) \subseteq A$ is prime, and hence $x$ is irreducible, but $x \in B$ is a unit.

Comment: Nice counterexample! (which answers my first question in the negative). Please, concerning my second question, do you think that adding the assumption "the invertible elements of both $A$ and $B$ are $k^*$" will yield a positive answer?

Comment: @user237522 I'm not sure, though I doubt it. If I think of something I'll let you know. In general, I think the "finitely-generated UFD's over an algebraically closed field" case is about the nicest one we can consider with these types of questions

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. Please notice that in my special case, $A=k[x^2] \subset k[x^2,x^3]=B$, $B$ is not a UFD (and $k$ is not necessarily algebraically closed, but your first counterexample shows we better assume that $k$ is algebraically closed).

Comment: Why did you stop at your example? Why not take $A=k[x^2], B=k[x]$? Clearly $x^2$ is irreducible in $A$, but not in $B$.

Comment: @leibnewtz In your example, $B$ is not a finitely generated $A$-module.

Comment: @Mohan Ah yes, you're right! I forgot about that condition. I was thinking finitely generated over $A$, which is not the same thing

Comment: @Mohan, very good counterexample! In a particular case I had in mind (not the above mentioned one), $A$ is a UFD and it is not known whether $B$ is a UFD or not. (1) If $B$ is a UFD, then this fact proves a claim I wish to get. (2) If $B$ is not a UFD, then it's ok to obtain that every irreducible element of $A$ remains irreducible in $B$ and then also get what I wished to get. (This is why I have taken $B=k[x^2,x^3]$).